# Should I learn the Linux API before delving into game development?

Tags: operating-system, game-engine

I have good knowledge of C++ and after reading [The Elements of Computing Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262640686) I have a basic knowledge of how computers work. I made a list of topics I want to learn next and books I want to buy on those topics. One of them is operating systems, but the one on the top of the list is Game development.

I am still a noob on those topics, so I wonder if I should know how an operating system (unix specifically) works before trying to learn game programming (Opengl, etc). On operating systems I have the book [Operating Systems by Tanenbaum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429388), and I want to buy The [Linux Programming Interface by Michael Kerish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200).

On game development I was planning on buying [Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) and [Game Coding Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1133776574) to acquire a general concept of game programming and how engines work and then learn Opengl.

I am really lost on what to do first and I hope this is an appropriate question. What should I learn first, what books should I read and in what order. Should I learn how a VGA works before trying Opengl? Are there any other topics I should know before delving into games programming. I am asking this because I like to know what I am coding, what the functions I am calling do under the hood, I don't like holes in my knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluffy opinion answer incoming. Take with grain of salt.

The nice thing about programming is that that you don't need to learn everything about everything to do one thing effectively. Knowing exactly how to implement a video driver isn't required for using OpenGL effectively. The point of OpenGL is to abstract that out so you don't have to worry.

Since you want to do game development, make a project. Like recreating Asteroids using OpenGL for graphics and writing all the game logic yourself. And set about completing it. In the process you'll learn much more than simply reading. Use books as reference. At least thats what I've found works for me.

The Operating Systems book is pretty good. Its the one I read in college. But those concepts presented in it, though interesting, are not something you'll have trouble learning simultaneously with game development or anything else.

Also you should read this: http://www.linuxforu.com/tag/linux-device-drivers-series/. It's a great article series that teaches linux driver development and operating systems concepts in the process.